# CUDA kernel launched after call to thrust is synchronous or asynchronous?

Tags: cuda, thrust

I am having some troubles with the results of my computations, for some reason they are not correct, I checked the code and it seems right (although I will check it again).

My question is if custom cuda kernels are synchronous or asynchronous after being launch after a call to thrust, e.g.

```
thrust::sort_by_key(args);
arrangeData<<<blocks,threads>>>(args);
```

will the kernel `arrangeData` run after `thrust::sort` has finished?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Assuming your code looks like that, and there is no usage of streams going on (niether the kernel call nor the thrust call indicate any stream usage as you have posted it), then both activities are issued to the *default stream*.  I also assume (although it would not change my answer in this case) that the `args` passed to the thrust call are device arguments, not host arguments. (e.g. `device_vector`, not `host_vector`).

All CUDA API and kernel calls issued to the default stream (or any given single stream)  will be executed in order.

The `arrangeData` kernel *will not begin* until any kernels launched by the `thrust::sort_by_key` call are complete.

You can verify this using a profiler, e.g. `nvvp`

Note that *synchronous* vs. *asynchronous* may be a bit confusing.  When we talk about kernel launches being asynchronous, we are almost always referring to the host CPU activity, i.e. the kernel launch is asynchronous *with respect to the host thread*, which means it returns control to the host thread immediately, and its execution will occur at some unspecified time with respect to the host thread.

CUDA API calls and kernel calls issued to the same stream are always synchronous with respect to each other.  A given kernel will not begin execution until all prior cuda activity *issued to that stream* (even things like `cudaMemcpyAsync`) has completed.